# MongoDB Update/delete Multiple documents based on Custom ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a mongo schema

```
   const taskSchema=new Schema({
    userID:{type:ObjectId,required:true},
  task: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    maxlength: 30,
  },
  finalDate:{type:Date,required:true},
  isFinished:{type:Boolean,required:true}
 })
```

what I need to get all the documents with a particular UserID and update/delete  .
I can use the find method to find all the documents with the required user id . After that I am at a loss on what to do.There will be multiple documents with same user id .
Any ideas on how to proceed will be a great help

Comment: MongoDB has an [`updateMany`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.0/classes/collection.html#updatemany) method.

Comment: update many can be used. what i need is how to get all the docs with userid and update /delete the documents with its own id

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

To update the first document matching the given condition

```
db.collection.update({
  "userID": ObjectId("5b87780c9ca8b03096a33380"),
  "task": "Cooking"
},
{
  $set: {
    "isFinished": true
  }
})
```

[Test Here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WT_8FzpeMa8)

To update all documents matching the given condition use **multi: true**

```
db.collection.update({
  "userID": ObjectId("5b87780c9ca8b03096a33380"),
  "task": "Cooking"
},
{
  $set: {
    "isFinished": true
  }
},
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Test Here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CXUcEPJ8AAs)

**Delete**

To delete the first document matching the given condition

```
db.collection.delete({ 
  "userID": ObjectId("5b87780c9ca8b03096a33380"),
  "task": "Cooking"
})
```

To delete all documents matching the given condition

```
db.collection.deleteMany({ 
  "userID": ObjectId("5b87780c9ca8b03096a33380"),
  "task": "Cooking"
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot worked like a charm. Changed upgrade to upgradeMany (the only one minute change).Accepted as answer

Comment: You are welcome